# Python TKinter Set absolute Label size

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am looking to set the Label Widget width to an exact value - `width=100` should be 100 pixels.

Is there a way to achieve this or should I be looking at using a different widget?

When using the TKinter Label, the `width` and `height` parameters refer to the text size - `height=2` will set the label large enough for two lines of text, not 2 pixels as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a blank image to the label, then you can specify `width` option in pixels:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

blank = tk.PhotoImage()
tk.Label(root, image=blank, text="Hello", width=200, height=50, compound="c", bg="yellow", bd=0, padx=0).pack(padx=100, pady=10)
tk.Label(root, image=blank, text="World", width=200, height=30, compound="c", bg="cyan", bd=0, padx=0).pack(padx=100, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If i try to update the text on the Image/Label - 

`labelTimer.config(text = str(gameTimer))`

...I get an error...

`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist`

If I search the error, none of the solutions seem to apply - can you shed a light on it?

Comment: @KevinRussell I cannot reproduce your issue when I try to change the text of the labels.  Did you put the code inside a function?

Comment: Yes the root is decalred outside the function

`def showScoreBatak():`
`    blank = PhotoImage()`
`    labelTimer = Label(root, image=blank, text='TIME REMAINING', font=("Arial", 25), fg="#000", bg="#fff", borderwidth=0, padx=103, pady=15, anchor='center', width=165, height=50, compound="c")`
`    labelTimer.place(x=20, y=25)`

Comment: Then in another function `labelTimer.config(text="0")`

Comment: `blank` is garbage collected after exiting `showScoreBatak()`. Also `labelTimer` cannot be accessed outside the function because it is a local variable.

Comment: @KevinRussell If you use `place()` on the label, you can simply use `.place(..., width=..., height=...)` and don't need to use a blank image.